# How can I make a function modify a variable C#

Tags: c#, function, variables, scope

Hi I am extremely new to C# and programing in general. I'm trying to make a text based adventure game as my first unguided project. I am sorting all of the attack/damage rolls into functions. But I cannot get functions to modify variables.

Does anyone know how I can get a function to modify a variable globally.

EXAMPLE CODE

```
class Program
{
public static int var = 10;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Maths();
        Console.WriteLine(var);
    }

    static void Maths()
    {   
        int var = 12;
    }
}
```

In this example I want the modified "var" to be printed as 12 but instead "var" is printed as 10.

This is my actual code which I want to use this principle in.

```
class Program
{
    //Char Stats
    static int playerMaxHealth = 50;
    static int playerHealth = 40;
    static int playerAttack = 10;
    static int playerLevel = 1;

    //Temp Stats
    public static int attackRoll;

    //Enemy Stats
    static int enemyMaxHealth;
    static int enemyHealth;
    static int enemyAttack;

    //Declar Random
    static Random randomObject = new Random();



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        attackRollFunc();
        Console.WriteLine(attackRoll);
        while(true)
        {
            if (playerHealth <= 0)
                death();
        }
    }


    public static int attackRollFunc()
    {
        int attackRoll = randomObject.Next(playerAttack);
        Console.WriteLine(attackRoll);
        return attackRoll;
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the code

```
static void Maths()
{   
    int var = 12;
}
```

You are declaring a new *local variable* named `var`. This is unrelated to the `var` *field* that you're trying to modify.

If you remove the `int` part from your method, it will do what you were expecting:

```
static void Maths()
{   
    var = 12;
}
```

Comment: While `var` is a legal variable name, it is also a non-reserved c# keyword. You should likely use a different name to avoid possible confusion.

Comment: Quite right, @andleer. There's a lot that could be improved in the code, but SO isn't really the place for that, so I left it out of my answer. [codereview.se] would be better.

Comment: Agreed but I usually try to point our these minor issues. My comment was directed at the OP not you.

Answer (score 4):

This code:

```
static void Maths()
{   
    int var = 12;
}
```

is declaring a new integer named `var` that is *only visible within this method*.  The `var` here is not the same `var` that is declared here:

```
public static int var = 10;
```

If you remove the `int` from inside your `Maths` method, you will effectively use the same `var` that is declared at the top of your class.

Answer (score 3):

Your method is creating a new local variable that just happens to have the same name as the static field, and initializing that to a value.  You need to instead simply access the existing field without declaring a new value.  Doing this is as simple as removing `int` from the method body and writing `var = 12;`.